# How do I use round brackets in an 'if' condition

Tags: bash, unix

I'm creating a bash script and somewhere inside I have this code:

```
if [ $# -eq 2 -a (! -r "$2" -o ! -f "$2") ]; then
echo "rvf: bestand \""$2"\" bestaat niet of is onleesbaar" 1>&2
exit 2
fi
```

When i try to run this inside the script I get this error:

```
Syntax Error (bash -n):
rvf: line 14: syntax error in conditional expression
rvf: line 14: syntax error near `-a'
rvf: line 14: `if [[ $# -eq 2 -a (! -r "$2" -o ! -f "$2") ]]; then'
```

How does '()' work inside Bash scripts?

Comment: Are you using `[` like your posted code or `[[` like in your error message?

Comment: BTW, note that neither `[` or `[[` is "`if` syntax"; they're independent commands, which can be used without `if` being involved (and `if` can be used without either of them; `if somecommand; then ...` will check whether `somecommand` returned a zero or nonzero exit status, whatever that command may be).

Comment: As an additional aside, `$2` should be in quotes to prevent its value from being subject to word-splitting and glob-expansion -- so you should just have `echo "...$2..."` instead of `echo "..."$2"..."`; if you want to prevent any characters directly concatenated on the right-hand side from being parsed as part of an attempted variable name, then `echo "...${2}..."` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[[` doens't support `-a`, and it is considered obsolete and non portable for `[`. The correct solution using `[` would be

```
if [ "$#" -eq 2 ] && { [ ! -r "$2" ] || [ ! -f "$2" ]; }; then
```

Grouping is done with `{ ... }` rather than `( ... )` to avoid creating an unnecessary subshell.

Using `[[` is simplifies to

```
if [[ "$#" -eq 2 && ( ! -r "$2" || ! -f "$2" ) ]]; then
```

Parentheses can be used for grouping inside `[[`; as a compound command, it uses separate parsing and evaluation rules, compared to an ordinary command like `[` (which is just an alias for `test`, not syntax of any kind).

In either case, [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) lets you refactor this to something a little simpler:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 2 ] && ! { [ -r "$2" ] && [ -f "$2" ] }; then

if [[ "$#" -eq 2 && ! ( -r "$2" && -f "$2" ) ]]; then
```

Comment: (Quoting `$#` also prevents problems with insane IFS values containing numeric characters when using `[` rather than `[[`, so it's not a bad practice regardless).

Comment: True; I'll just drop the comment and imply that it is necessary :)

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple points of confusion here.

- `[` can (as an optional XSI extension to the standard) support `(` as a separate word (meaning **there needs to be spaces around it**), *but [the POSIX sh specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) marks it (like `-a` and `-o`) as "obsolescent" and advises against its use*.
- `[[` *does* support `(`, but again, it needs to always be a separate word.

Don't do that at all, though. You're using only well-supported and portable functionality if you keep each test its own simple command and combine them only with the shell's boolean logic support.

That is:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 2 ] && { [ ! -r "$2" ] || [ ! -f "$2" ]; }; then
  echo "rvf: bestand \"$2\" bestaat niet of is onleesbaar" >&2
  exit 2
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your logic.
"Not A or Not B" is just a more complicated way to say "not (A and B)".

In `bash`, try

```
if [[ "$#" == 2 ]] && ! [[ -r "$2" && -f "$2" ]]; then
```

Better,

```
if [[ "$#" == 2 && -r "$2" && -f "$2" ]]
then : all good code
else : nope code
fi
```

Even better,

```
if [[ "$#" == 2 ]]            # correct args
then if [[ -r "$2" ]]         # is readable
     then if [[ if -f "$2" ]] # is a file
          then echo "all good"
               : do all good stuff
          else echo "'$2' not a file"
               : do not a file stuff
          fi
     else echo "'$2' not readable"
          : do not readable stuff
     fi
else echo "Invalid number of args"
     : do wrong args stuff
fi
```

Clear error logging is worth breaking the pieces out.

Even *better*, imho -

```
if [[ "$#" != 2 ]]
then : wrong args stuff
fi
if [[ ! -r "$2" ]]
then : unreadable stuff
fi
if [[ ! -f "$2" ]] 
then : do not a file stuff
fi

: do all good stuff
```